# DictReader not printing ordered dictionary in python 3.8.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use DictReader function in python. It was supposed to print an Ordered dictionary but it is printing only as a normal dictionary like this

{'name': 'raj', 'email': 'raj@gmail.com', 'phone': '+12345'}

{'name': 'jar', 'email': 'jar@gmail.com', 'phone': '+54321'}

{'name': 'arj', 'email': 'arj@gmail.com', 'phone': '+23451'}

```
from csv import DictReader

with open('sample.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_reader = DictReader(f)
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Regular dictionaries are ordered in Python 3.8. What is your expected output?

Comment: Ordered dictionary does not mean ordered alphabetically. The order in which key+value pairs are added is maintained.

Comment: @jakub  
I was expecting the output like this:-  
  
OrderedDict([('name': 'raj'), ('email': 'raj@gmail.com'), ('phone': '+12345')])  
  
OrderedDict([('name': 'jar'), ('email': 'jar@gmail.com'), ('phone': '+54321')])  
  
OrderedDict([('name': 'arj'), ('email': 'arj@gmail.com'), ('phone': '+23451')])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question isn't clear in what your expected output was. But I think what surprised you is that `csv.DictReader` gives a regular dictionary in python 3.8, whereas you expected an `OrderedDict`.

The answer is that this behavior changed in python 3.8. [According to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

> Changed in version 3.8: Returned rows are now of type dict.

[In python 3.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), you see the following:

> Changed in version 3.6: Returned rows are now of type OrderedDict.

Comment: yes,  thanks for the clarification.  This is what exactly happened.

Comment: Great, if this was the answer to your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the green arrow.

Comment: Note that the ordering information is still there. *"Since dicts are now keeping insertion order as of 3.7, we can switch to the more efficient construction of dict rather than OrderedDict for each row in the CSV file."* as noted in https://bugs.python.org/issue34003